# How can I get an HDC object from a CDC object?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, cdc

I have an object, dc, of type CDC and I'd like to get an HDC object.

I read the MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yf45f1t%28VS.80%29.aspx), but don't really understand it.

Can someone provide me with a brief example/explanation on how to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CDC class has `operator HDC()` defined which allows the compiler to convert a CDC object to HDC implicitly. Hence if you have CDC* and a function which takes HDC then you just dereference the pointer and send it to the function.

Answer (score 15):

When you have `CDC` object it will be implicitly converted to `HDC` when necessary:

```
CDC dc;
HDC hdc = dc; // HDC hdc = dc.operator HDC();
```

If you have pointer to `CDC` object then using function `GetSafeHdc` will look more clear:

```
CDC* pdc = SOME;
HDC hdc = pdc->GetSafeHdc();
```

Answer (score 3):

`CDC` is a C++ class which - to a reasonable approximation - encapsulates an HDC, which is a handle to a device context.

The documenation which you link to describes a conversion `operator`, which is a C++ construct that classes can supply to allow implicit conversion from an instance of a class to some other type. In this case the implicit conversion results in the underlying handle (HDC) which the `CDC` instance encapsulates.

You can perform the conversion by using a `CDC` instance anywhere were it needs to be converted to an `HDC`.

Most simply:

```
void f( const CDC& cdc )
{
    HDC hdc = cdc;

    // use hdc here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
HDC hDC = dc;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just assign it.

```
CDC cdc = something.
HDC hdc = cdc;
if (hdc != 0)
{
  //success...
}
```